# How to get full video download from a link?

Tags: java

I am trying to download a video from a link, but it only downloads a small part of it, so it can't be watched at all. How would you download an entire video no matter how large the file is from a link?

```
    try {
        URL url;
        byte[] buf;
        int byteRead, byteWritten = 0;
        url = new URL(fAddress);
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationDir + "\\" + localFileName));

        conn = url.openConnection();
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((byteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            byteWritten += byteRead;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this link contains entire video file?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes positive. WHy does it look like it should work?

Comment: Yes, it worked fine for me (except I didn't download video but other 10Mb file).

Comment: @Pshemo I tried downloading a video believe it was 26mb and it only downloaded 6006 bytes hmm maybe I ended the program too soon. Is there a way to print a message after it's done because it printed done before I closed it.(The print statement was after the while loop)

Comment: Placing that print statement right after loop should be fine and indicate that you downloaded and stored all send data (assuming that non exception was thrown in `finally` block responsible for closing file). This suggests that server may intentionally send you corrupted file, or you didn't use proper address/headers (maybe you need to be logged so cookies could be important; or server could require proper user-agent).

Comment: @Pshemo Downloaded Successfully.
File name:"test.mp4"
No ofbytes :742

Comment: @Pshemo I just thought about something it asks me to log in to get access to link on the site

Comment: That address preforms redirections and you are not following them. You need to read new location and try to read from it. Here is example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/

Comment: @Pshemo so I should add a new function with all that copy & paste?

Comment: I am writing method which should help you. Give me a minute (or ten).

Comment: Ok thanks I really appreciate it. It really helps a lot. Do you have a wishlist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like server may redirect you to other location which your code doesn't handle. To get final location you can try method like (based on: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/):

```
public static String getFinalLocation(String address) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(address);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    int status = conn.getResponseCode();
    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
    {
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
            || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
        {
            String newLocation = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
            return getFinalLocation(newLocation);
        }
    }
    return address;
}
```

Now you simply need to change

```
url = new URL(fAddress);
```

to

```
url = new URL(getFinalLocation(fAddress));
```

Comment: Alright it's running now I wish I knew how to do a loading bar

Comment: @J.Doe Feel free to ask new question then (right after you make sure that it wasn't asked yet using search query like: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+loading+bar)

Comment: It worked. I wouldn't ask how to make a loading bar on this site it would be closed soo quick.

Comment: @J.Doe You are right, asking *for* code is not what we like here. But asking *about* problem with code is OK. So try to write it first (find example/article about it) and if you will have problems you could ask new question. If you describe it well someone may be willing to help you. For now all I can say is that: (1) to get size of file you are downloading in bytes you can use `conn.getContentLengthLong()` (it returns value of `content-length` header as `long`), (2) amount of bytes downloaded already is in `byteWritten` (3) so you simply need to update your progress-bar in each iteration.